# Rotation Y not working on some phones

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have a property `ViewPropertyAnimator` that rotates `ImageView` on axis y

```
animate().rotationY(180).alpha(0).setDuration(300).start();
```

it's working well but in a Huawei device it disappears `ImageView`. I changed `rotationY` to `rotation` and it was working. What is wrong?

Comment: did you find a fix for this ? I'm having the same problem on huawei devices with rotationY. ty

Comment: no it's not fixed yet @nvasilescu

Answer (score 1):

try to use `view.setCameraDistance(10 * view.getWidth());`

Comment: Please explain your code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: this is huawei devices bug, 10 in this case - magic number. But you should this method when rotateY to make anim more beauty. So you can take number instead 10 empirically